# Editor or plugin that allows CSS styles to be edited like they are in Google Chrome

Tags: text-editor, css

In Google Chrome it's possible to tab through all the properties in a CSS selector in the developer tools, editing as you go along. The tab key-press event will automatically insert a new property or value, or select the next property or value, depending on its position.

In comparison a standard text editor seems cumbersome. One must use the mouse or arrow keys and select. The tab key will just insert a tab or trigger auto-completion.

Does an editor exist that is configurable to behave in the same way as Chrome dev tools or alternatively a plugin for Sublime Text or similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), a free and open source editor that offer you a live preview of your CSS in your default web browser. 
You can change values of your html and css and get directly a result without refreshing the page every time.